# Woocommerce Price filter not working in Divi theme builder

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, divi-theme

I am using Divi for 4 years. Recently I have been working with Woo-commerce and getting conflicts with the theme. For instance, the price filter does not work in the Divi theme but works just fine with any default theme of WordPress like twenty seventeen. Tried the default and third party woo-commerce filter by WOOF. I am currently using the Divi 4.6 version and the latest version of Woo-commerce.

Here are the screenshots before and after using the price filter:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t5eF.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1buhF.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRFJ0.png

Comment: You can use the divi theme option " Filter products by price " widget to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It's known problem.

1. solution is using Ajax in woof. Use this in short code: `is_ajax=1`
   But probably you'll have 404 error when you'll refresh the page
2. Simple solution is Themify – WooCommerce Product Filter. It works, I've used it before. **But there is a problem with it, if your using Polylang, like in my case right now**

Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/themify-wc-product-filter/

Tutorial for Divi: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/how-to-create-filtered-sidebars-for-your-divi-woocommerce-pages?

Answer (score 0):

For that only one plugin works: https://wordpress.org/plugins/themify-wc-product-filter/

Also, you can follow the following article by Divi Official Team: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/how-to-create-filtered-sidebars-for-your-divi-woocommerce-pages

Hope it works. :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30349983)